# Как поместить свойство метода в таблицу

Tags: php

Мне нужно поместить данный массив в таблицу

```
     News Object
    (
        [news_id:News:private] => 120
        [news_is_deleted:News:private] => 
        [news_subject] => Test
        [news_body] => bla bla bla blablav м bla bla bla bla blablabla
        [news_date] => 2018.01.26
    )

    /////////////////
    <?php
class News{
private $news_id;
private $news_is_deleted;
public $news_subject;
public $news_body;
public $news_date;

function create($subject, $body, $date){
$subject = htmlspecialchars($subject);
$body = htmlspecialchars($body);

$this->news_subject =$subject;
$this->news_body = $body;
$this->news_date = $date;

$db = $this->get_connect();

$query = 'INSERT INTO news SET
news_subject = "' . $subject .'",
news_body = "' . $body .'",
news_date = "' . $date .'";
';

mysqli_query($db, $query);
$this->news_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

}
function del($news_is_deleted){
$this->news_is_deleted = $is_deleted;

$db = $this->get_connect();

$query = " SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `news_is_deleted`= '".$deleted."'
";



if($deleted = 1){

}

mysqli_query($db, $query);
$this->news_id = mysqli_select_id($db);
}

private function get_connect(){
define ('HOST', 'localhost');
define ('USER', 'root');
define ('PASS', '');
define ('BASE', 'news');

$db = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, BASE);
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf-8');
return $db;
}
}
echo "<pre>";
$subject = 'Test';
$body = 'bla bla bla blablav м bla bla bla bla blablabla';
$date ='2018.01.26';

$news = new News();
$news->create($subject, $body, $date);
print_r($news);

//$news = new News();
//$news->del($subject, $body, $date);
//print_r($news);

echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
foreach ($news as $key =>$value) {
echo "<tr><td>".$value['news_id:News:private']."</td><td>".$value['news_is_deleted:News:private']."</td><td>".$value['news_subject']."</td><td>".$value['news_body']."</td><td>".$value['news_date']."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Какая структура таблицы должна быть?

Comment: А что здесь массив, а что таблица?

Comment: моя ошибка, это свойство метода